# UIScreen mainScreen in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios9, iphone-privateapi, uiscreen

We have a problem with iOS SDK in Xcode 8.

We use method `[UIScreen mainScreen]` in our project. This method is available from iOS 2.0.

But when we built product in Xcode 8 and submited it for review, app was rejected. Surprise: in the new SDK (**Xcode 8 GM**) this method marked as “*available from iOS 10.0*”. In other words - now iOS 9 identifies `[UIScreen mainScreen]` as “*non-public API*”.

Perhaps this is Apple’s bug.

**Our question:**
1) We want to continue using this method.
2) We want to support iOS 8 and iOS 9.
3) We want to use Xcode 8.
**Is that possible?**

Answer (score 0):

Class properties are an Objective-C feature available in Xcode 8 and it looks like `mainScreen` has been refactored in the API [to be one](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscreen/2097556-mainscreen?language=objc). The error of mainScreen being non-public seems like a misleading error/bug on Apple's end, but if you use the class property accessor the error *might* go away.

The good news is, since it is a language feature, not iOS version specific, you should be able to adopt class property syntax, i.e. `UIScreen.mainScreen`, and continue to support iOS 8-9.

p.s. `mainBundle` is also now a class property, so if you use that, it's possible it would trigger the same error.