# UIMainScreen is not a function error NativeScript iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I am trying to run my NativeScript-Application on iOS Emulators. Since iTunes wants Apps to be published by Xcode 9.0 or later, I had to upgrade from NativeScript iOS v3.1 with Xcode 7.3 (where my App ran perfectly fine) to NativeScript iOS v4.2 with Xcode 9.0. Now sadly I cannot execute my App on any device. It is starting all the way and I see the loadingscreen and then it runs into this error:

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:419:27: Unhandled Promise rejection: UIScreen.mainScreen is not a function. (In 'UIScreen.mainScreen()', 'UIScreen.mainScreen' is an instance of UIScreen) ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: UIScreen.mainScreen is not a function. (In 'UIScreen.mainScreen()', 'UIScreen.mainScreen' is an instance of UIScreen)
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:421:23: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: UIScreen.mainScreen is not a function. (In 'UIScreen.mainScreen()', 'UIScreen.mainScreen' is an instance of UIScreen)
```

When I go back to Xcode 7.3 with NativeScript-iOS 3.1.0 it works perfectly fine again. I have no clue what I could do to fix this issue.

I have seen some related questions with UIScreen.MainScreen errors (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549461/uiscreen-mainscreen-in-xcode-8)), but they seem to be native-iOS related which I cannot influence from NativeScript (at least I don't know how I could).

Now here is some stuff of my config:

package.json:

```
{ //...
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "4.2.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "0.3.1-2016-08-04-787",
    "nativescript-calendar": "1.1.2",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "1.3.2",
    "nativescript-fresco": "1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ng2-translate": "1.1.1",
    "nativescript-social-share": "1.3.0",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "1.3.1",
    "ng2-translate": "2.2.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.4.4",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "url": "0.10.3",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.10.4",
    "babel-types": "6.10.2",
    "babylon": "6.8.1",
    "filewalker": "0.1.3",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "0.3.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "0.0.20",
    "typescript": "1.8.10"
  }
}
```

build.xcconfig:

```
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer;
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = %Number%;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.1;
```

info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>%App_Name%</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2.0.9</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2.0.9.4</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>iPhoneOS</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>my app needs access to the calendar to create new entries</string>
    <key>Minimum </key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>%ip%</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that your `tns-core-modules` is an older version (approx 2 years old) and is using already deprecated iOS API where the `mainScreen` was a function (now it is a property). You have updated only the tns-ios runtime which is working with the new iOS APIs while the code in the old `tns-core-modules` is using the old APIs. In two words - that won't work and you will have to update `tns-core-modules` and `nativescript-angular` + all related dependencies.  You might have to also update your code-behind files here and there.

Upgrade instructions for the `package/json` dependencies can be found [here](http://The%20thing%20is%20that%20your%20%60tns-core-modules%60%20is%20old%20and%20is%20using%20already%20deprecated%20iOS%20API%20where%20the%20%60mainScreen%60%20was%20a%20function%20(now%20it%20is%20a%20property).%20You%20have%20updated%20only%20the%20tns-ios%20runtime%20which%20is%20workign%20with%20the%20new%20iOS%20APIs%20while%20the%20code%20in%20the%20old%20%60tns-core-modules%60%20is%20using%20the%20old%20APIs.%20In%20two%20words%20-%20that%20won't%20work%20and%20you%20will%20have%20to%20update%20%60tns-core-modules%60%20and%20%60nativescript-angular%60%20+%20all%20related%20dependencies..%20%20You%20might%20have%20to%20also%20update%20your%20code-behind%20files%20here%20and%20there.)

Breaking changes that need to be considered when migrating from 2.x.x [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/Modules30Changes.md)

See also the CHANGELOG for the `tns-core-modules` [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

And lastly, the CHANGELOG for `nativescript-angular` can be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)